# Symbolic Computations in boost libraries

Tags: c++, boost

Does Boost library support symbolic computations and integration  ?
If yes, can any one gives an example.
In fact, i had tried many symbolic libraries, like Vienna Math and symbolicc++
but i am facing problems in configuration, so returned to Boost.

Comment: [odeint](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/libs/numeric/odeint/doc/html/index.html) does integration

Answer (score 0):

No. You can find a full list of boost math libraries here: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/?view=category_Math

If you're having trouble using C++, why not try SymPy (Which you can try online through http://www.sagemath.org/). Or mathematica/maple/matlab if you have access t them.

Comment: I had already seen theses math boost library, but get nothing. No, the troubles only with the mentioned two libraries, my project is written in c++ language and i am forced to continue with c++

Comment: can we call python fom c++ ?

Comment: There is boost.python (among others), but I wouldn't describe it as easy to configure. It is often easier to call c++ from python instead, which you can do with cython or cffi.